# autogen is no longer available in CentOS 9?

Tags: centos, yum

I'm unable to install autogen on CentOS 9, is that package removed now?

```
# yum clean all
# yum search autogen
Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:57 ago on XXX
No matches found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is in the list of [removed packages in RHEL 9](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html-single/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_9/index#removed-packages_assembly_changes-to-packages) and it also isn't available in [EPEL](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/)  so if you need it, you have to install it manually. You can also [fill a bug](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/epel-package-request/) to request it to be added to EPEL.

Comment: nice! Because "you need to build a package that exists for other versions of RHEL/EPEL/Fedora"  comes up more often than I would have thought, I supplemented your answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/705906/106650)

Answer (score 4):

Go and upvote [Vojech's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/705879/106650); it's right and this one only extends it:

You have a package that was (intentionally?) not included in RHEL9. That shouldn't be stopping you from building a package yourself!
Building things as packages has advantages:

1. someone with distro expert knowledge has tricked the build system into working on your specific system before, applied distro-specific patches and so forth
2. installing something as a package means you can uninstall it cleanly, if the package becomes officially available later on, it can be upgraded without conflict from the official repos, and things end up being in distro-standard directories
3. If you have other RPM packages which depend on `autogen` as a package being installed, they will now build

So, let's build a redhat/fedora/centos/rocky/alma/scientific linux… RPM package from distgit!

Small caveat: autogen has a build-time dependency on guile22, which isn't avaiable for EPEL8, but for EPEL9. So, for anyone experimenting with this on CentOS 8, they'll have to build `guile22` first. Not a bad fate! I've included it below:

```bash
sudo dnf install 'dnf-command(config-manager)' 'dnf-command(builddep)' 
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools
sudo dnf install --refresh epel-release git
sudo dnf install --refresh fedpkg

# ==Guile22: RHEL8 specific==
# in EPEL8, guile22 wasn't available, which is a build dependency of autogen
# so do this only on CentOS/RHEL/Rocky/Alma 8:
git clone https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/guile22.git
cd guile22
## Install build dependencies
sudo dnf builddep guile22.spec
## build
fedpkg local
## install
sudo rpm -i x86_64/guile22-*.rpm
cd ..
# ==End of RHEL8 specifics==

# ==autogen==
git clone https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/autogen.git
cd autogen
sudo dnf builddep autogen.spec
fedpkg local
rpm -i x86_64/autogen-*.rpm
```

And that's it!

Comment: Wrote a more [general version of this as reference Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705910/i-need-a-package-for-my-version-of-rhel-epel-centos-fedora-but-its-only-packag).