# I need a package for my version of RHEL/EPEL/CentOS/Fedora, but it's only packaged for other versions of Redhatoids

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, rpm, packaging

I'm often in the situation where I backport some fedora-packaged software to CentOS, or forward-port something from an older version of EPEL to Fedora, or vice versa.

How can I do that with the least amount of effort?

Comment: This is an abstraction of my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/705906/106650)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, that's what distgit is for: keeping package specs coordinated and available. So, let's use it.

We'll need to set up our system to be able to build packages:

```bash
# only on CentOS and other RHEL derivatives:
sudo dnf install 'dnf-command(config-manager)'
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools
sudo dnf install --refresh epel-release 
# all:
sudo dnf install --refresh fedpkg 'dnf-command(builddep)' git
```

First, find your package on https://src.fedoraproject.org/browse/projects/ . I'm using `guile22` as an example:

Great, at this point we have all we need to build packages! Let's go to the [`guile22` distgit site](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/guile22/) as we found with the search, and click on the "clone" button; we're presented with the URL `https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/guile22.git`.

```bash
pkgname=guile22
# clone the distgit
git clone "https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/${pkgname}.git"
cd "${pkgname}"

## Ask dnf to install build dependencies
### if this fails, read diligently – packages might have changed names and you might
### need to slightly edit the .spec file, or you might need to build the missing 
### dependencies yourself, just like you're building this package, before you can
### continue.
sudo dnf builddep "${pkgname}.spec"

## build
### `fedpkg local` executes the build "unisolatedly" on this very distro.
### Instead of that, you could also omit the `dnf builddep` step above and do a
### `fedpkg mockbuild`. This will take a bit longer, as it needs to set up a clean
### build chroot. Often it's worth it.
fedpkg local
## install
### `fedpkg local` put the RPMs into $arch subdirs, so on my machine those are `x86_64`
### and `noarch`, but if you build for e.g. ppc64, that might be different.
sudo rpm -i x86_64/${pkgname}-*.rpm
```

And that's it!

Comment: Why not use `fedpkg clone`? That avoids having to search for the package on the web site.

Comment: true, I didn't do anything other than re-package fedora packages, let me fix that later on

Comment: Or instead `fedpkg local` and `dnf builddep` you can run `fedpkg srpm` and submit the srpm to https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/ which will build it for you and will host the dnf repository.

Comment: also very nice, but for most cases where you just want to backport something for your own purposes, a bit over the top, @msuchy. I do that for unpackaged software, sometimes!